# Fail to send two parameters in http post request

Tags: android

I trying to make http - post call. 
The server that i send him this request need to have two parameters
   1. first parameter is Int
   2. second parameter is enum that i sending as string

I try to do it in two ways and them both fail:

First way:

```
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("intVal", "-100")); 
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("enumVal", "enumAsString"));  
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

I get 'bar request' as a response.

Second way:

```
      DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + METHOD_NAME);
try
{
     HttpParams postParams = new BasicHttpParams();
           postParams.setIntParameter("intVal", -100 ); 
           postParams.setParameter   ("enumVal" , "enumAsString" ); 

           httppost.setParams(postParams);

           HttpResponse p = httpclient.execute(httppost);
      }
      catch(Exception e) 
      {

                  .... 

      }
```

In this way i see that the server get the parameters - but the first parameter ( that need to be int ) is 0 and the second parameter ( that need to be enum ) is 0 also.

P.S : The code that run on the server is WCF code - using REST.

Please .. i must solve this issue ...

Thanks.

Comment: What's running on the server? Do you have access to it to add some debugging to see what's received? Knowing what's sent back isn't of any particular use if you don't know if your code is even sending the right data to begin with.

Comment: The code that run on the server is WCF code - using REST

Comment: Show the full code which you are using to send a request to web server.

Comment: full code added to the 'second way'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is two different ways which you can send param with `HttpPost` and `HttpUrlConnection` using Andorid :

**First Way :**

```
HttpClient httpclient;
HttpPost httppost;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httppost = new HttpPost("your login link");


postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "param1_value"));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", "param2_value"));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

**The second way is :**

```
        String charset = "UTF-8";
    String query = String.format("debug_data=%s&"
                            + "client_auth_hash=%s&" 
                            + "timestamp=%s&"
                            + "client_api_ver=%s&",
                            URLEncoder.encode("1", charset),
                            URLEncoder.encode(hash, charset),
                            URLEncoder.encode(timeStamp, charset),
                            URLEncoder.encode(clientApiVersion, charset));

        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000); //miliseconds
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Charset", charset);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = connection.getOutputStream();
            output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (output != null)
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        int status = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
        Log.d("", "Status : " + status);

        for (Entry<String, List<String>> header : connection
                .getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
            Log.d("Headers",
                    "Headers : " + header.getKey() + "="
                            + header.getValue());
        }

        InputStream response = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

        int bytesRead = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[30 * 1024];
        while ((bytesRead = response.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        //read the response in pieces if it's needed
            byte[] buffer2 = new byte[bytesRead];
        }
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The both ways are working properly.

Answer (score 2):

This works in my case.. Try this and let me know what happen..

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname","test"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pws","test"));
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);  
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8));

// Execute HTTP Post Request  
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nothing from the ways warking 
but this is way that i solve this problem and its work fine

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
 json.put("intVal", -100);
 json.put("enumVal", enumAsString);


 StringEntity t = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8");

 httppost.setEntity(t);


 httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
 httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```